# Is there a cheat tool for speed hacking games that run under WINE?

Tags: wine, games

I'm playing some old games under WINE and want to enable some kind of speed hack to get past the mundane parts. On Windows I can accomplish this with [Cheat Engine](https://cheatengine.org/).

Cheat Engine's speedhack is done through DLL injection which doesn't seem to work with WINE. I started up my game, then loaded CE and targeted the process. But the speed hack fails with the following error:

> failure determining what realgettickcount means

I'm guessing that the DLL injection failed as this may not be possible between WINE processes.

Is there a way to get some kind of speed hack working for my WINE games?

Comment: @kemotep, it's a question about Wine (a software for Linux).  It certainly wouldn't be on-topic on a site about Windows.  I don't see any reason it should be closed.